# Best way to use Vue with Express?

Tags: express, vue.js

1: I did Installed expressjs.
2: I installed vue framework using npm install vue --save
3: I used handlebar as template-engine for expressjs

After this in index.hbs this is code :

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>Welcome to {{title}}</p>
<p>\{{title2}}</p>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            title2: "Hello World"
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now i wanted to use vue to execute that script but thing in layout.hbs i tried but don't know how to include vue so i just added vue from cdnjs.

There was also a problem i added that in head couldn't include in body end because template render by hbs not executing script.

Now second thing is when i want to use vue in users.hbs i have to create Vue Instance again and this continue with more coming pages.

It repeating code and very difficult to manage.

So any way ? i don't have to create instance every time and i don't need to include script in head tag from cdn ?

Sorry for forget this if i add Vue new instance in app.js then this is warning :

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.
(found in <Root>)
```

This is layout.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.2/vue.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
        {{{body}}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please note that using bundler such as Webpack is common in modern JS frameworks.

Comment: So then i think Vue-cli best way right ? but i also don't know how to use express with that :)

Comment: Once you have your webpack package setup you can pull in express (and anything else your project needs) from npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express then import it it into your project.

Comment: Thanks @craig_h i will try it

Comment: @craig_h i just tried this but default nodejs modules like dns, fs are not working and it saying me to install using npm why ? these are default in nodejs.

Comment: Have you imported them by doing `import fs from 'fs';` and `import dns from 'dns';`

Comment: yes i did, i think with web pack it will not work because now i created vue-cli project and webpack compile all files, also don't know why not picking default nodejs modules :) so i have to choose one vue or express.

Comment: You can try the https://github.com/express-vue/express-vue package to add it as a template engine instead of handlebars

Answer (score 3):

FOR SSR
I would suggest to use NUXT.js coz they have an integrated system with express already installed. Use axios for http requests.

FOR CSR
I would suggest to build 2 projects separately, in 1 you have vuejs and in another nodejs. Then let them communicate by using axios, for this purpose you can use EXPRESS or RESTIFY.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and stumbled upon this question before setting out to make a solution myself.

In the end I went with the default express generator app + a build script to convert .vue files into a bundle so I can use them in my view files.

I wrote a small post on the steps to take:
https://mindthecode.com/using-vue-components-in-your-express-app/

Hope it helps someone.